# Add space between bullet and text in td

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, unicode, html-table

How to add space between *bullet point* and *text* in `td` tag

Code in `c#` forming `html`:

```
.....
names.Add("<tr><td>");
names.Add("\u2022    " + collection.name);
names.Add("</td></tr>");
.....
```

I tried with `\u2022` with little space leaving at the end as in above code.
But, I am not to get the space in between bullet and text.

How to get the space in between bullet and text?

Comment: use &nbsp; as many as you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `&nbsp;` for adding space in html

```
names.Add("&nbsp;" + collection.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

**`&nbsp;`** Have you tried that html code for spacing?